# Adding values to Ensure [on top of present and absent]

Tags: puppet

Ensure by default in puppet provides "present" and "absent". Is there way in which we can have "present", "absent" and "modify" ?

Can you provide me with a link for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Valid values for the `ensure` attribute are specific to the defined resource. Puppet is designed to ensure a defined state, and I don't see how you could ask Puppet to define a state that changes during every execution. I haven't given this too much thought, but if I understand your question correctly, this is either **stateless** or an **undefined state**. In either case, Puppet relies on idempotence, and a scenario that demands a modified state for each run is just not idempotent.